# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') Django extends

Tags: javascript, html, django

I know this is bit common to ask but I'm still confused why it didn't read the `classlist` it says error in the console. I just want to pops the toaster when button was click

I've tried putting js scripts in different places because The JS script tag should run after the HTML elements have been declared. The DOM element exists before accessing, still don't have any idea why it doesn't work what I did.

```
<script src="{% static 'assets/vendor/libs/toastr/toastr.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/ui-toasts.js' %}"></script>
```

**transaction.html**

```
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-label-primary add-data">Click button</button>

{% block footer_scripts %}
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add-data').click(function (event) {

      const toastAnimationExample = document.querySelector('.toast-ex');
      let selectedType, selectedAnimation, selectedPlacement, toast, toastAnimation, toastPlacement;

      if (toastAnimation) {
        toastDispose(toastAnimation);
      }

      toastAnimationExample.classList.add('animate__fadeInRight');
      toastAnimationExample.querySelector('.ti').classList.add('text-success');
      toastAnimation = new bootstrap.Toast(toastAnimationExample);
      toastAnimation.show();

        // Dispose toast when open another
      function toastDispose(toast) {
        if (toast && toast._element !== null) {
          if (toastPlacementExample) {
            toastPlacementExample.classList.remove(selectedType);
            toastPlacementExample.querySelector('.ti').classList.remove(selectedType);
            DOMTokenList.prototype.remove.apply(toastPlacementExample.classList, selectedPlacement);
          }
          if (toastAnimationExample) {
            toastAnimationExample.classList.remove(selectedType, selectedAnimation);
            toastAnimationExample.querySelector('.ti').classList.remove(selectedType);
          }
          toast.dispose();
        }
      }
    });
});
</script>
{% endblock footer_scripts %}
```

Comment: Which `classList` is it erroring on?

Comment: @mykaf everything that contains `classList` Still don';t know how to fix this